# How to fix 0x800CCC0E Error Codes?

Tags: windows, gmail, sockets

I recently started receiving the above-mentioned error which is apparently a Winsock error message it is preventing me from checking my e-mail with Gmail, although there is no problem with my e-mail was ATT e-mail and MSN mail. I found a number of supposed fixit programs which found a great number of errors in my registry (although Wyse and Glary did not find anything wrong with my registry?) And offered to fix them for a fee. I would much rather not pay! :-)

Does anybody here know what is causing this error and how to fix it? oh – I am using Windows 7/ultimate and Live Mail as my e-mail reader.

Thank you.

Ross

Comment: Did you look at this: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/tFsI9dJUCSM/d4qE0UOlyVMJ ?

Comment: Can you post a little more info on the actual error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

This is bizarre! I have two external USB drives. For some reason the writing-to-disk red-LED was on yet the drive itself could not be found. I turned the drive off and turned it back on and wiggled the USB cable. I got the familiar USB doink sound. The disc-access light stayed off, I could access the drive normally and I can now send and receive e-mail as I used to: problem solved.

Why would a loose USB cable manifest itself as a Winsock Error?!?!

In any case, problem solved.

Ross

Answer (score 0):

Check server requirement from settings
Open Outlook.
Open File > Tools > Account Settings.
On the Account Settings window, click on the E-mail Tab. The following window should open.
Select your email account from the list.
A new window called Email account should open. On it find the “More Setting” button and click it.
The following “Internet E-mail Setting” window should open.
Open the Outgoing Server tab.
On it, check the “My outgoing server (SMTP) required authentication” box.
Click on OK to apply the changes.

Once the process is complete, restart Outlook and check if error code 0x800ccc0e persists.

and we have also provied different error codesslution ;LIKE :-[Hulu error code DRMCDM78](https://theerrorcode.com/how-to-fix-hulu-error-code-drmcdm78/)